# How to troubleshoot router configuration for home webserver

Tags: networking, webserver

How to troubleshootI installed lighttpd on my home computer and configured my router to allow external connections to port 80. When I start the webserver at 127.0.0.1:80, I can access 127.0.0.1 in a browser so I know the web server is running. However, get "Connection refused" error when I tried a.b.c.d:80 in a browser, where a.b.c.d is my external IP which I got from whatismyip.com. I thought my ISP blocks port 80 so I changed my router to forward port 81 to port 80 on my computer. But a.b.c.d:81 also gives "Connection refused". I tried other ports too but always get "connection refused". Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some good troubleshooting steps are

you did 127.0.0.1:80   ok

A) Try to connect from your LAN (so, 192 address)

B)Try a port scan of port 80 https://www.grc.com/shieldsup

Bear in mind that you trying to connect to your external IP from within your network, won't always work, it depends on whether your router has a feature that supports that so better to check connecting to your external from another machine e.g. the port scan.

C) Try netstat -aon  see if the server is not just listening but listening on 0.0.0.0:80 (so accepting all) and not 127.0.0.1:80 (accepting local only) or 192.168.0.3:8 (an example of it accepting LAN only)

And if any of these fail you can check the windows firewall too.

Comment: I think point c might be the reason. I configured lighttpd to  listen on 127.0.0.1:80. Should I change it to 0.0.0.0:80 or 192.168.x.y:80 (my LAN IP)? By the way, what is the expected result of a port scan by grc.com?

Comment: @user4127551 grc.com's "explanations"has some FUD. But, results of his or any scan are useful. open means it's accessible.  Closed or Stealth(stealth being a term he uses for when it won't respond at all) means not accessible or not running.    Gibson is criticised for many things but critiques of him here tend to get deleted. Though for all his flaws, his port scanner seems to be available/up more than most.

Comment: @user4127551 If you only want to access your Web server from your LAN then have it listen on a LAN IP of the computer it sits on e.g. 192.168.x.y:80  But you seem to want to access it from the Internet so have it listen on 0.0.0.0:80   You can also use the Windows Firewall to restrict what IPs can connect to it e.g. grc port scan, and a few computers you'll be accessing it from. Then it's still listening on 0.0.0.0:80 but with windows firewall making some restrictions